# How can I correctly implement an Angular Guard?

Tags: angular, http, observable, angular-router-guards

I'm implementing an AdmingGuard in angular to protect some routes.

ADMIN GUARD:

```
  // --------------ADMIN GUARD
  
  // want protect routes from user who are not Admin
  canActivate(): boolean {
    // isLogged() service method: set 2 global boolean variable in teh service:
    //- 'isLogged'= true if the user is logged in
    //- 'adminLoggedIn' = true if the logged user is an Admin
    this.authService.isLogged();

    // getIsAdminLogged() service method: return value of global var 'adminLoggedIn'
    const adminLoggedIn = this.authService.getIsAdminLogged();

    if (adminLoggedIn) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

SERVICE:

```
// SERVICE 

  //here global variable:
  loggedIn: boolean; // the user is logged ?
  adminLoggedIn: boolean; // the logged user is an Admin ?

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  // this makes an Http Request to the server sending the AccessToken
  // and control if the user that sent the AccesToken is logged and if is an Admin
  isLogged() {

    // get the AccessToken from localStorage, if is empty: im sure the user is not logged
    const accessToken = this.getAccessToken;
    if (typeof accessToken === 'undefined' || accessToken === null) {
      this.loggedIn = false;
      this.adminLoggedIn = false;
      return;
    }

    // here makes the https ruquest to the server 
    return this.http
      .get<any>(this.isLoggedUrl)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler))
      .subscribe(
        (res) => {

          // server send back the 'res' response 
          // control in the 'res' if the user is logged and if the user is an Admin
          // in base on this controls, set the 2 global var 'loggedIn' and 'adminLoggedIn'

          if (res.status == 200) {
            this.loggedIn = true;
            if (res.userType == 'admin') {
              this.adminLoggedIn = true;
            }
          } else {
            this.adminLoggedIn = false;
          }
        },
        (err) => {

          // server sand back some error
          // control if the error is 'TokenExpiredError' (in that case try to refresh the tokens)
          // otherwise set the 2 vars 'loggedIn' and 'adminLoggedIn' to false

          if (err.error.message == 'TokenExpiredError') {
            const refreshToken = this.getRefreshToken;
            if (typeof refreshToken === 'undefined' || refreshToken === null) {
              this.loggedIn = false;
              this.adminLoggedIn = false;
            } else {
              // refresh tokens if possible
              // also this method set the var 'loggedIn' and 'adminLoggedIn'
              this.refreshTokens();
            }
          } else {
            this.loggedIn = false;
            this.adminLoggedIn = false;
          }
        }
      );
  }

   // return the value of the global var 'adminLoggedIn'. 
  getIsAdminLogged() {
    return this.adminLoggedIn;
  }
```

**THE PROBLEM IS**

Following the order of the statements in the CanActivate it should execute:

- isLogged(); inside isLogged() is executed the HTTP Request to verify if the user is logged and if the user is an admin. So isLogged() set in the service 2 global var 'loggedIn' and 'adminLoggedIn ' to true or false.
- getIsAdminLogged(); get the value of 'adminLoggedIn' to check if the user loggedin is an Admin ( the goal of this Guard)

but the HTTP request is no async so getIsAdminLogged(); is executed before that HTTP request has verified if the user is an admin or not.

I have read some solutions about it but I'm still confused.

THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change all code blind, tell me if something doesn't work

**ADMIN GUARD**

```
async canActivate(): boolean {

    this.authService.tokenValid()

    let that = this

    await this.authService.isLogged().then(res => {
      if (res.status == 200) {
        that.authService.setStatusUser(true)
        if (res.userType == 'admin') {
          that.authService.setStatusUser(true)
        }
      } else {
        that.authService.setStatusAdmin(false)
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      if (err.error.message == 'TokenExpiredError') {
        that.authService.setRefresh()
      } else {
        that.authService.setError()
      }
    });

    // getIsAdminLogged() service method: return value of global var 'adminLoggedIn'
    const adminLoggedIn = this.authService.getIsAdminLogged();

    if (adminLoggedIn) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

**SERVICE**

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

...some code ...

setStatusAdmin(status: boolean){
    this.adminLoggedIn = status;
  }

  setStatusUser(status: boolean){
    this.loggedIn = status
  }

  setError(){
    this.loggedIn = false;
    this.adminLoggedIn = false;
  }

  setRefresh(){
    const refreshToken = this.getRefreshToken;
    if (typeof refreshToken === 'undefined' || refreshToken === null) {
      this.loggedIn = false;
      this.adminLoggedIn = false;
    } else {
      // refresh tokens if possible
      // also this method set the var 'loggedIn' and 'adminLoggedIn'
      this.refreshTokens();
    }
  }

  tokenValid(){
    const accessToken = this.getAccessToken;
    if (typeof accessToken === 'undefined' || accessToken === null) {
      this.loggedIn = false;
      this.adminLoggedIn = false;
    }
  }

  isLogged(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http
      .get<any>(this.isLoggedUrl)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler)).toPromise()
  }
```

Comment: `await this.authService.isLogged().toPromise();`
this gives me an error: ' Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'Subscription' '
and `async canActivate(): boolean { ` and gives me : ' The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type. Did you mean to write 'Promise<boolean>'? '

Comment: ohhh you return a suscribe.... that it's a bad practice. Wait me for a moment I'm rewrite the answer.

Comment: Please check the code, change everything blindly, there may be an error ... tell me if something is missing.

Comment: THX Derek.. I will check it as soon as possible, meanwhile, I would understand if there is some way to solve it keeping the Observable (not converting it in a Promise)

Comment: Your welcome. The problem with an Observable is do you want to wait the response... is for that a parse that to Promise.

Answer (score 0):

```
 loggedIn: boolean;
```

instead of boolean value assing it to "null"

```
 loggedIn:null
```

in the guard file `this.authService.getIsAdminLogged()` will return observable. Guard will wait till this observable in "complete" state. in admin guard file, return this:

```
import { take, skipWhile, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

//http service returns observable
return this.authService.getIsAdminLogged().pipe(
      skipWhile((value) => value === null),
      // if the value is null, we are not getting any value, we are getting either false or true and faking that this observable is complete
      // before u were getting false by default. the issue was while app component checking for authentication, guard would consider that it was false, maybe 1 second later it gets the answe as true
      // to prevent this issue we are giving the final result to the guard
      take(1),
      //tap() does not modify the incoming value
      tap((authenticated) => {
        if (!authenticated) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
        }
      })
    );
```

Comment: thx for the answer, but is not so clear how skipWhile and take and tap are working...